# Is directly linking to an image okay for images uploaded to the server with a custom PHP script?

Tags: php, url, encryption, hyperlink

For an image file (JPEG) that has been uploaded to the server via a PHP script (to a directory such as `http://www.somedomain.com/images`, is it a good idea to allow the client to get the image's direct address (such as `http://www.somedomain.com/images/someimage.jpg` and paste it into a WYWSIWYG text editor (such as TinyMCE)?

I am wondering if there is a preferable method where the direct address is encrypted?

Please, if I should just link directly to the image, just say so.

Thanks!

**Note:** *I have modified this question from my original. Please see revisions if you are curious, but I think I was asking the question incorrectly. My apologies to the people who already answered.*

Comment: Define "secure" in this context.

Comment: @Lasse I mean "secure" as in is it okay to reveal the exact location of the image?

Comment: I take it that I don't need to worry about security in this situation?

Comment: Yes, linking directly is perfectly ok. Moreover, with TinyMCE and other WYSIWYG editors, you have an option to give your client a nice image selector combined with image uploader, which will also check file extensions, and do more things to ensure smooth and secure WYSIWYG editing.

Comment: ... by 'more things' above I also meant automatic and on-request images resizing, Lightbox-style linking of thumbnails to fullsize images, and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you check correctly WHAT is being uploaded, it shouldn't be a problem. So please at least use `getimagesize` or a similar function to make sure it's an image that's being uploaded, AND make sure the extension on the file is correct so that it will never be run through the PHP interpreter - to prevent someone from uploading an image with a PHP script attached.

BTW Here's a nice whitepaper on uploads and security : http://www.scanit.be/uploads/php-file-upload.pdf

Comment: There is no simple "Yes" or "No" answer. If you consider what @wimvds said, the answer is "Yes." Otherwise it is either "No" or "Yes, at your own risk".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the CPU Constraints of your web-hosting service you can write a service to 'serve' the images to your users.

**Here is some very BASIC code, it needs spiffing up and cleaning up for XSS/etc...**

```
<?php
$basePath = "/path/to/my/image/store/not/web/accessible/";
$file = NULL;
if (isset($_GET['file']))
  $file = $_GET['file'];

if ($file != NULL)
{
   $path = $basePath . $file; 
   // $file needs to be checked for people 
   // trying to hack you, but for the sake of simplicity
   // i've left it out

   $mime = mime_content_type($path);
   $size = filesize($path);
   header("Content-Length: " . $size);
   header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
   header('Expires: 0');
   readfile($path); // Outputs the file to the output buffer
}
?>
```

Obviously you can put whatever security checks in here you want. But this way your files are below the web dir, and you can apply logic to thier accesibility. This is **typically** used more for FILE vs. Images, but you can do the same thing here.

Images Accessed like this

`http://www.mysite.com/image.php?file=hello.jpg`

And you can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite urls like this:

`http://www.mysite.com/images/hello.jpg

Into the first url.

**I Cannot stress enough the need for further security checking in the above example, it was intended to show you how to serve a file to the user using PHP. Please don't copy & use this verbatim.**

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses direct links for images. The permalink function simply puts the image on a page along with metadata for comments, but the images' SRC attributes still link directly to the image.

Answer (score 0):

why are you concerned about revealing your image location. Hotlinking?
if so you can prevent hotlinking with htaccess

http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

Comment: I'm just curious. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you get your answer already?
Every site reveals image location to the browser. It's just the way web works.

Got any reason to "encrypt" original location?

Comment: Well, I am asking if there would be a reason.

Comment: And, no I don't believe I have a clear answer yet. I feel like you could provide it, though!

Comment: @letseatfood my eyes tell me that **everyone** has told you there is not a single problem. Open any site in the world and see. And **think**. It is not as hard as it seems.

Comment: Yes, albeit indirectly. And, just mimicking what other people do for no other reason than "I see that is what they do" is not a good reason. Thanks for your feedback. It's always sparkly.

Comment: @letseatfood well, nuff said. Your question has no good reason, indeed. That's what I am talking about. Follow your own words, find yourself a more sensible question.